# Why can't I add existing contacts to my Telegram account?

Tags: contacts, telegram

I can't add more contacts to my Telegram account. They said "[Name] is not on Telegram yet, would you like to invite them to join?" but the contact is indeed already existed on Telegram.

So I just want to know if there are any solutions and suggestions that I could do to deal with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I can't I add contacts on my Telegram?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246714/why-i-cant-i-add-contacts-on-my-telegram)