# Why I can't I add contacts on my Telegram?

Tags: contacts, telegram

I can't add more contacts to my Telegram account. They said "[Name] is not on Telegram yet, would you like to invite them to join?" but the contact is indeed already existed on Telegram. I change my phone already and the setting was good but still the same I can't add anybody on my Telegram.

So I just want to know if there are any solutions and suggestions that I could do to deal with this. Please help me.

Comment: Almost exact dupe, but not answered yet: [Why can't I add existing contacts to my Telegram account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242200/44325)

Comment: I think I had this same problem and I had to change my privacy settings to public, then asked the other party to discover me and send me a message so that I could add them in my contact list.

Answer (score 1):

Their privacy settings is hiding the info from you.

Tell them to send their telegram username from Telegram> hamburger menu > settings > username. There also is a link that opens direct chat with them.