# Can't add more contact to my Telegram

Tags: contacts, telegram

I can't add more contacts to my Telegram account. They said "[Name] is not on Telegram yet, would you like to invite them to join?" but the contact indeed already exists on Telegram.

So I just want to know if there are any solutions and suggestions that I could do to deal with this.

Comment: Possible exact duplicate: [Why can't I add contacts on my Telegram?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246714/44325)